# Facebook API: Get a row from MySQL and Like an Object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Well I'm to make a Facebook MySQL and PHP project, but I'm getting an error I don't what is it
there's a page and a input (text) the user inputs and id of facebook Post, the user hits a submit button which sends the data via jQuery to like_object.php which its code is:

```
<?php
    require 'facebooksdk/facebook.php';
    $id = trim($_POST ['postid']);

    if(empty($id)){
        die("forbidden");
    } else {
       $token  = $_GET["accesstoken"];

       include('config.php');

       //Create facebook application instance.
       $facebook = new Facebook(array(
           'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
           'secret' => $fb_secret
       ));

       $output = '';

       //get users and try liking
       $result = mysql_query("
          SELECT
              *
          FROM
              W3 
       ");

      if($result){
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
              $m = $row['access_token'];
              $facebook->setAccessToken ($m);

              try {
                  $facebook->api("/$id/likes", 'POST');
                  $msg1 = "<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Success</strong></div>";
              } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                  $output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' failed to like.</p>";
                  $msg2 = "<font color='red'>Failed to Like!</font>";
              }
          }
      }
      mysql_close($result,$connection);
  }
?>
```

I checked the error log (facebook SDK generates it)

```
[16-Jul-2013 15:25:29] PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for mysql_close() in /home/like_object.php on line 43

[16-Jul-2013 15:27:24] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/like_object.php on line 33
```

So where is the wrong in my php?

Comment: `php -l yourscript.php` shows no syntax errors. Did you paste your code *as is*?

Comment: yeah, is facebook sdk (version or something like that) has something with that? and maybe it's my html page that doesn't the post id to like_object.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the latest version of [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) 
maybe that's will help

Answer (score 1):

```
trim($_POST ['postid']);
```

Needs to be

```
trim($_POST['postid']);
```

And

```
$msg1 = "
       <div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Success</strong></div>
";
```

Needs to be

```
$msg1 = "<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Success</strong></div>";
```

And

```
mysql_close($result,$connection);
```

needs to be

```
mysql_close($connection);
```

Also, `mysql is deprecated`. Please have a look into [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)

And

```
$facebook->setAccessToken ($m);
```

Needs to be

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($m);
```

Comment: It didn't work with these edits I got a new error 
`[16-Jul-2013 16:30:10] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/like_object.php on line 32`

Comment: @AnnaSkylar Your code is broken everywhere. `$facebook->setAccessToken ($m);` has an extra space, and needs to be `$facebook->setAccessToken($m);`

Comment: You are wrong, the parses doesn't complain about those extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to change:

```
$id = trim($_POST ['postid']);
```

to:

```
$id = trim($_POST['postid']);
```